# Communication of Flexray COM to Application

Tags: autosar

How are FlexRay signals configured or mapped? How are they communicating from an application to FlexRay COM via RTE?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Flexray Com", there is only Com that serves as the interaction layer for signal-based communication for all bus systems. Com offers an API towards the Rte which the latter can call to feed values into or extract values out of Com.

The configuration of how a value in the application ends up in a Flexray Pdu is really a mouthful, i.e. this requires a lengthy explanation that would take way too much space to do it in this format. Instead of explaining everything in detail, I'd like to point to a couple of relevant documents.

In particular, I'd recommend having a look into the documents "TPS System Template" for the signal configuration and the mapping between signals and the application software, "TPS Software Component Template" for understanding how the application software and data types are configured, and "SWS Rte" to understand the binding between Rte and Com. All of these documents are available for download off of the AUTOSAR website.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, but this is more theoretical approach is mentioned. As I have to go through all documents which you have mentioned in Autosar, So It will take time to go through this stuff. Is there any sample code base available for understanding?

Comment: If you want the information quick, you may want to book a training offered by some companies. Other than that, I fear that there is no shortcut. If you need to understand the big picture it will take time. A code sample won't help much if your primary problem is to understand the configuration and modeling aspect.

Comment: Thank you So much for your inputs. It will help me for the further understanding.